# correct syntax for form_for url in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is probably simple, I'm still coming to terms with rails syntax. What is the right syntax to pass the address_id in the url for form_for to a modified route?

This is the form - note the "address_id parameter"

```
  <div class="one_fourth floatcenter">
    <%= form_for address, :url => edit_address_path(:id => address.id), :method => :get do |f| %>
        <%= content_tag(:button, :class => 'btn btn-inverse') do %> Edit Address
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

And this is the route I've configured:

```
get "edit_address/:id" => "member/addresses#edit"
```

Id is not being passed to the controller for some reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form_for address` should be enough if address is a persisted object, but if it's not enough, then `form_for address, url: edit_address_path(address)` is what you want.

Comment: nice one, thought it must be an easy one. Appreciate the help. It's taking me awhile to get across rails coming from java...

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple.  In place of `url`, you put your post method route:

```
<%= form_for(@post, url: super_posts_path) do |f| %>

...  
<% end %>
```

**You also call by action**

```
 <%= form_for @friend,:url=> { action: "create_friend"} do |f|%><br>
  <%= f.label :u_from %>
      <%= f.text_field :u_from %>
     <%= f.label :u_to %>
     <%= f.text_field :u_to %>
    <%= f.submit%>
 <% end %>
```